# Showing that a A measurable function is integrable over the union of two sets iff its integrable over each set individually.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Im trying to show that if we have a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $f:X\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ an $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function and $A,B\in{\mathcal{A}}$ two disjoint sets, then $f$ is integrable over $A\cup{B}$ iff $f$ is integrable over $A$ and over $B$.

Ive been toying around with the definitions but can't really seem to get anywhere. I understand the intuition.

Comment: Which definition of "integrable over $A$" is used? Is it "$f$ is integrable over $A$ if (and only if) $f\cdot \chi_A$ is integrable"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\int_{A\cup B} |f| \; d\mu = \int_A |f|\; d\mu + \int_B |f|\; d\mu$.

Comment: This holds, of course, because $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Comment: If we didn't have that, we would use $\int_A |f|\; d\mu \le \int_{A \cup B} |f|\; d\mu$, $\int_B |f|\; d\mu \le \int_{A \cup B} |f|\; d\mu$, and $\int_{A\cup B} |f|\; d\mu \le \int_A |f|\; d\mu + \int_B |f|\; d\mu$.